# Domain specific content generation - RAG or fine-tune?

Tags: llm, prompt-design, fine-tuning, text-generation, genai-ecosystem

I am exploring requirements for a project whose final output is a Markdown file where, the contents of the file are generated by a LLM. The contents will be similar to "Executive Summary" of subjects such as clients, technology, market trends, etc. Each of the subject has a datastore - internal or external. The Executive Summary may be upto 1000 words.

**Prompt**

```
Write a report on the revenue trends of ABC Corp. in the FY 2023. 
Describe the organisation chart with employee strengths.
```

**Response**

```
ABC Corp. has a Monthly Recurring Revenue of USD 1 million where 70% of the revenue came mainly from re-selling.....
ABC Corp. is led by Mr X....
```

What are the differences between the following approaches?

1. Implement RAG with internal data-stores.
2. Fine-tune a LLM say, Mistral with the internal data-stores.

Answer (score 1):

Fine-tuning is generally useful when you want more than one query to use the same information. For instance, OAI's [docs](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/common-use-cases) emphasize its use in "style, tone, format, or other qualitative aspects". I would suggest using fine-tuning if, for instance, you find you cannot reliably get the summary to be ~1000 words in length, or if you find that the tone is not sufficiently "executive summary"-like or doesn't prioritize the right information in a summary.

However, fine-tuning takes time, and so it'd be impractical to fine-tune a model every day for every company you care about just to ask it one question. RAG, by contrast, is just a way to provide more information in a prompt. That makes it very good for providing up-to-date information when (and if) it is queried for. Use RAG (or similar methods to provide information in the prompt) to provide the most recent information.

[Here's OAI's discussion of when to use RAG vs fine tuning](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/when-should-i-use-fine-tuning-vs-embeddings-retrieval-augmented-generation)

(Obligatory disclaimer that making financial/investment decisions based on an LLM's summary is probably about as smart as making investment decisions based on a prophetic mule, and providing LLM's summaries to others might leave you on the hook for any hallucinations that your LLM invents.)

Comment: "However, fine-tuning takes time, and so it'd be impractical to fine-tune a model every day for every company you care about just to ask it one question. " That is the follow-up question I have. How often should one fine-tune? I am trawling the Net to better answer this question.

Comment: https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/347/2269 Similar question. How does one verify if results from fine-tuning are better than prompt engineering?